# Errors when retrieving user details from Microsoft Graph using oauth2-microsoft

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am using [oauth2-microsoft](https://github.com/stevenmaguire/oauth2-microsoft) to develop a 'sign in with Microsoft' tool for my app. I'm successfully authenticating and receiving a token, but then I receive an error from the sample code.

I am using the sample code below and have tried various combinations of URLs in the 'urlResourceOwnerDetails' field, including leaving it blank.

```
$provider = new \Stevenmaguire\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Microsoft([
  'clientId'                  => '<redacted>',
  'clientSecret'              => '<redacted>',
  'redirectUri'               => 'http://localhost/test.php',
        'urlAuthorize'              => 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize',
        'urlAccessToken'            => 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token',
        'urlResourceOwnerDetails'   => 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive'
    ]);

    $options = [
        'scope' => ['wl.basic', 'wl.signin']
    ];
```

After this comes authentication and token generation.

Then this line throws errors:

```
$user = $provider->getResourceOwner($token);
```

A token is definitely being generated, as I can `echo $token` and see it.

The above code should create a `$user` object that contains details about the logged in user. However, instead it generates these errors:

If `'urlResourceOwnerDetails'` is set to `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive` I get:

```
League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Exception\IdentityProviderException: Access token is empty
```

If `'urlResourceOwnerDetails'` is set to `https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me` I get:

```
UnexpectedValueException: Invalid response received from Authorization Server. Expected JSON.
```

And if `'urlResourceOwnerDetails'` is empty I get:

```
GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException: cURL error 3: malformed (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
```

Any ideas, please?

Comment: Could you please share your plan? So far I understand you want to get token and with that token trying to access Graph API right?  But which grant_type you are using for?

Comment: Hi, sorry - I simply want to use it for sign in, so I want to check their email address against my database and retrieve basic things like their name.

Answer (score 2):

It appears [`oauth2-microsoft`](https://github.com/stevenmaguire/oauth2-microsoft/issues/12) does not support Microsoft Graph Auth to a full extent at the moment, refer for example [this thread](https://github.com/stevenmaguire/oauth2-microsoft/issues/12)

Regarding the error

> League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Exception\IdentityProviderException:
>   Access token is empty

access token is expected to be passed as `Authorization` header but according to [`Microsoft.php` provider](https://github.com/stevenmaguire/oauth2-microsoft/blob/master/src/Provider/Microsoft.php) implementation it is passed instead as  query string:

```
 public function getResourceOwnerDetailsUrl(AccessToken $token)
{
    $uri = new Uri($this->urlResourceOwnerDetails);
    return (string) Uri::withQueryValue($uri, 'access_token', (string) $token);
}
```

The way how library is designed, the following provider class could be introduced to support Microsoft Graph calls (by including access token in the `Authorization` header of a request)

```
class MicrosoftGraphProvider extends AbstractProvider
{

    /**
     * Get provider url to fetch user details
     *
     * @param  AccessToken $token
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getResourceOwnerDetailsUrl(AccessToken $token)
    {
        return 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me';
    }


    protected function getAuthorizationHeaders($token = null)
    {
        return ['Authorization'=>'Bearer ' . $token->getToken()];
    }


    public function getBaseAuthorizationUrl()
    {
        return 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize';
    }

    public function getBaseAccessTokenUrl(array $params)
    {
        return 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token';
    }


    protected function getDefaultScopes()
    {
        return ['openid profile'];
    }

    protected function checkResponse(\Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface $response, $data)
    {
        // TODO: Implement checkResponse() method.
    }


    protected function createResourceOwner(array $response, AccessToken $token)
    {
        return  (object)$response;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Vadim. I'm not sure I understand properly, but are you suggesting that I should be amending/extending oauth2-microsoft in order to fix this.

To be honest, I'm quite shocked at how difficult it is to implement a basic sign-in check for Microsoft in comparison to Google. Can anybody point me in the direction of an idiot's guide, please?

Comment: Did you have any luck? I am stuck with the same error message...!
Laravel 6 isn't working, although the sample code works with 5.4